# C++ Read access violation for vector

Tags: c++, visual-studio, exception, access-violation

Im getting an exception when I`m trying to use vector[int_number] and my program stop working.

```
            uint64_t data = 0xffeeddccbbaa5577;
            uint16_t *vector = (uint16_t*) data;

            int currentPosition = 0;

            while (currentPosition <= 3) {

            uint16_t header = vector[currentPosition]; // problem here
```

Visual Studio 2017 returns me:  Unhandled exception thrown: read access violation.
vector was 0x6111F12.

Im stuck here. If you have any idea what I should do I`ll be grateful. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with this code? Because whatever it is this is not the right way to do it. Ask the right question and you may get a helpful answer.

Comment: What can I do to obtain a vector with four elements on 16bit? I.e. vector[0] = 5577, vector[1]=bbaa etc?

Comment: @Flavinia Declare an array of four 16bit numbers and use `memcpy` to copy bytes from `data`. IRC, this is the only legal way. BTW, you likely wanted to write `uint16_t* vector = (uint16_t*)(&data);`

Comment: A relevant article: [Type Punning, Strict Aliasing, and Optimization](https://blog.regehr.org/archives/959).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By accessing the data through a pointer of different type you obtained by casting you wander off into **undefined-behavior-land**. Instead of this, try the following (note I also replaced your while loop with a ranged for loop avoiding to have to keep a counter)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

int main() {
    uint64_t data = 0xffeeddccbbaa5577;
    uint16_t vector[4];
    memcpy(vector, &data, sizeof(uint64_t));

    for (uint16_t header : vector)
    {
        std::cout << std::hex << header << std::endl;
    }
}
```

yielding

```
5577
bbaa
ddcc
ffee
```

If you use `reinterpret_cast` you hold two pointers of different type pointing to same address which may easily lead to undefined behavior. `memcpy` avoids that by creating a copy of the memory location and you may safly access it with a pointer of a different type. Also take a look into [type-punning (as pointed out by @DanielLangr)](https://blog.regehr.org/archives/959)

Comment: Gcc sees through the memcpy, and does the expected thing with optimization. What about MSVC?

Comment: @RobertAndrzejuk In this very simple example it does, [see compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/mKhh4l). I hope I didn't do a mistake so quickly.

Answer (score 5):

Setting aside all the undefined behaviour you get due to *strict aliasing* violations, in the current crop of Intel chips and MSVC runtime, all pointers are 48 bits.

So `0xffeeddccbbaa5577` is **never** a valid pointer value.

So the behaviour on dereferencing that value will be undefined.

If you wanted to break up `data`, into four elements of an appropriate type, then one method is to create a `uint16_t foo[4]` say and `memcpy` the data starting at `&data` to `foo`.

Comment: Okay, I understand. 
But what can I do to obtain a vector with four elements on 16bit?
I.e. vector[0] = 5577,  vector[1]=bbaa  etc?

Comment: @Flavinia this answer shows the real problem: in your code you're interpreting value of `data` as a pointer rather than, as suggested in other answers, reinterpert the meaning of variable as array of 4 16-bit values.

Answer (score 1):

It's really very easy, but you were **so** far off with your original attempt that you've confused everyone.

```
 uint16_t vector[] = { 0x5577, 0xbbaa, 0xddcc, 0xffee };
```

Ask the right question, if you'd asked the question you have in the comments we'd have got there a lot quicker.

Comment: `uint64_t data = 0xffeeddccbbaa5577;` here is just an example. Im getting data on 64 bit from memory, and the reason I asked this question is because I didnt now I should use **reinterpret_cast**.

Comment: @Flavinia and in my humble opinion you shouldn't use reinterpret_cast to type-pun even though it may work on some compilers (see type-punning). Doing so leads to the dark side of the standard -- **undefined-behavior** ;)

Comment: I really dont know why, but I have run the project and it works perfectly fine.

Comment: @Flavinia This is what undefined-behavior means. It works today on your compiler, but may fail tommorow after a patch (which is very unlikly, as this would break a lot of code which previously worked and often pisses people off), but still, if you are aware of an alternative, do not use it. Your alternative here is to make a copy with `memcpy` which you should use. Why not take the safe route?

Comment: Oh, okay. I understand now. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a concrete example that should avoid any undefined behavior due to strict aliasing / "illegal" casts / etc., since this seems to be what you're actually interested in.

This code takes a `std::uint64_t`, copies it into an array of four `std::uint16_t`s, modifies the values in the array, and then copies them back into the original `std::uint64_t`.

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  std::uint64_t data = 0xffeeddccbbaa5577;
  std::uint16_t data_spliced[4];
  std::memcpy(&data_spliced, &data, sizeof(data));
  std::cout << "Original data:\n" << data << "\nOriginal, spliced data:\n";
  for (const auto spliced_value : data_spliced) {
    std::cout << spliced_value << " ";
  }
  std::cout << "\n\n";

  data_spliced[2] = 0xd00d;
  memcpy(&data, &data_spliced, sizeof(data));
  std::cout << "Modified data:\n" << data << "\nModified, spliced data:\n";
  for (const auto spliced_value : data_spliced) {
    std::cout << spliced_value << " ";
  }
  std::cout << '\n';
}
```

With output (on my machine):

```
Original data:
18441921395520329079
Original, spliced data:
21879 48042 56780 65518

Modified data:
18441906281530414455
Modified, spliced data:
21879 48042 53261 65518
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to take the address of that variable if you want to assign it to a pointer

```
const uint16_t* vector = reinterpret_cast<const uint16_t*>( &data ) ;
```

NOTE:
This works on MSVC 2017, but...

> This is a truck load of undefined behaviour! – Bathsheba

As cpprefrence for [`reinterpret_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast) says:

> 5) Any pointer to object of type `T1` can be converted to pointer to object of another type `cv T2`. This is exactly equivalent to `static_cast<cv T2*>(static_cast<cv void*>(expression))` (which implies that if `T2`'s alignment requirement is not stricter than `T1`'s, the value of the pointer does not change and conversion of the resulting pointer back to its original type yields the original value). In any case, the resulting pointer may only be dereferenced safely if allowed by the type aliasing rules (see below)
>
> ...
>
> Type aliasing.
>   Whenever an attempt is made to read or modify the stored value of an object of type DynamicType through a glvalue of type AliasedType, the behavior is undefined unless one of the following is true:
>
> 1. AliasedType and DynamicType are similar.
> 2. AliasedType is the
>      (possibly cv-qualified) signed or unsigned variant of DynamicType.
> 3. AliasedType is std::byte (since C++17), char, or unsigned char: this
>      permits examination of the object representation of any object as an
>      array of bytes.
>
> Note that many C++ compilers relax this rule, as a non-standard language extension, to allow wrong-type access through the inactive member of a union (such access is not undefined in C)

The above code does not fulfill any of the Aliasing rules.

Comment: This is a truck load of undefined behaviour!